# Convert a HTML page to a iOS View

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

i want to take a normal html page (a page from tf2 wiki) and convert it into a view.
For example it should take a text and put it into a label or a Image into an UIImageView.
Is there any Framework to do something like that or should i convert the site on a webserver 
to make it easier for the app at runtime to render ?
Hope you understand, what i want to do.
Tim

Answer (score 2):

there could be different ways depending on your scenario, you could load them in UIWebView within IOS, If you don't want show the UIWebView then you can get the html from it ans use it however you want. or other way you could transfer the HTML as json data to IOS and then show that data via UIView, UILabel or anything else. otherwise as suggested by Zakaria, you could use PhoneGap.

**UPDATE** with sample code for sending a request and getting its contents if you don't want to use UIWebView

```
       //your html page with url  
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];


        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];

        NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

            if ([data length]>0 && error==nil) {

                NSString *html=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                NSLog(@"this string contains all html page you have \n %@",html);
            }
   }
     ];
```

Comment: What do i get when i convert the html to json ? DO you have any example that shows a website as json ? And how do i convert the json file to a normal view ?

Comment: you would get a json object data which you will have to parse on the IOS side to get the contents, you could get this data as `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray`, you could parse them and use however you want, there are plenty of code examples available over internet for json data parsing in IOS. but I am wondering why not just load UIWebView and load the html and view it within UIWebView?

Comment: I have added some sample code within my answer, you could have a look if this approach suits you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand the question properly, but Cordova lets you develope iOS apps in html/css/js.
Check their website: http://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: No, i dont want to create a app from html, i want to show html content in an app with iOs objects like the imageview and textlabel.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is a static one, then use PhoneGap : It will embed your HTML+JS+CSS in an iOS app  and will be loaded in a webview.

But there is no framework that will allow you to convert your HTML elements into native ones.

Comment: Okay, i dont want to use Phonegab, but do you have a idea how to write own methods to convert ?

Comment: Well ... create a public project on GitHub, commit your first code lines and find a community ;)